# A different approach to 100 push-ups / 20 pull-ups challenge

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, push-ups, endurance

Many trainer websites and apps for challenges such as 200 squats, 100 push-ups, 20 pull-ups, etc., have you do five sets of certain repetitions every other day.

I wanted to run by you a different approach, to know your thoughts on it, and whether anyone has already tried it successfully.

Instead of increasing the number of reps every other day, I propose to do 100 push-ups at increasing levels of difficulty. So on day one, we will do 100 push-ups at a near vertical position. Then, every other day, we will increase the difficulty by moving to a more horizontal position. Eventually, we should be able to do 100 push-ups at a proper horizontal push-up position.

My hypothesis is that by doing the target number of reps right from the beginning, we'd be conditioning the body to handle it and the weakest link in our body may be more apparent.

It may also be more motivating, since you should be able to do the target reps at the easiest difficulty and it may be easier to increase the difficulty, by even 1%, as opposed to gearing up to a certain required number of reps.

You can also do push-ups/pull-ups at a higher difficulty and can move to a lower difficulty, while working out. You may also only spend the same amount of time, each time, since you are doing the same number of repetitions every other day.

The alternative would be to use bands to ease your push-ups/pull-ups, and you'd do the regular training with a different band, each time you complete the challenge.
Example: Complete the 20 pull-up challenge with a blue band, then green, then purple, red, and without any.

I think I'll try a mix of the two for now.

Comment: Have you ever read Convict Conditioning by Paul Wade?

Answer (score -1):

> I am a hard gainer and while I have managed to get myself to around 25 push-ups in a row, the 100 push-ups and 10+ pull-ups still remains elusive.

1) There's no such thing as ''hard gainer'', if you can't build muscle you are either not training enough or not eating enough.

2) If your goal is to do more than 10 pull ups and more than 25 push ups, just train to failure. Get on the ground and do as many push ups as you can in one set without stopping, keep going until you fall and your chest hits the ground, if you push yourself you will easily do 40 or more push ups on your first try so you will be almost half way through, all you'll need to do is to keep doing 1 set to failure every day and in a week or two you will be able to do 100 push ups in a row because endurance is quite easy to build up.

Comment: I'd strongly disagree. My goal is 100 push-ups and 20 pull-ups. The maximum push-ups in a row that I have attained is 22 and maximum pull-ups is eight. I couldn't work out much in December due to illness, so my current max pull-up is six. I attained 22 push-ups in a rows after practicing for more than a month.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes, training till failure will work. Your rep count will increase.